# Current Period calculation that considers date part changes

Tags: parameters, tableau-desktop, calculated-field

I am working on a dashboard in **Tableau Desktop** that needs to compare current period vs previous period metrics, considering different date parts (day, month, quarter etc).

In order to do so, I created `Start Date`, `End Date` and `Date Part` parameters, and these calculated fields that will be used as date periods the client will get to choose from:

`Current Period` = ([Date] >= [Start Date] AND [Date] <= [End Date])

`Previous Period` = (DATETRUNC([Date Part], [Date])>=
DATEADD([Date Part],-[Number Days CP/PP],[Start Date]-1)
AND DATETRUNC([Date Part], [Date])<=[Start Date]-1)

Then I use this `Current Period` and `Previous Period` fields to build the metrics, for example: `Current Period Clicks` = SUM(IIF([Current Period],[Clicks],NULL)) and `Previous Period Clicks` = SUM(IIF([Previous Period],[Clicks],NULL)). The issue is that when I change the date part parameter it does not change this metric, it remains the same... any idea why?

How could I change the parameters/calculated fields so any current period metrics would consider the `Date Part` changes?

Thank you for the help!